# analytic nature of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous function.If $f^2$ and $f^3$ are analytic is it true that $f$ is analytic?
Tried it using definition of analytic function but not yielding anything.Neither found any counter examples.

Comment: Since $f = {f^3 \over f^2}$ it is certainly analytic where $f(x) \neq 0$ :-).

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is never zero?@copper.hat

Comment: We certainly know that $f$ is meromorphic. Now, a zero of $f^2$ is most certainly a zero of $f^3$ and since the order or multiplicity of the zero for $f^3$ is greater than the same zero for $f^2$, $f^3/f^2$ has no poles. So $f$ is in fact holomorphic.

Comment: Thanks @Chris KWill the problem hold if continuity of $f$ withdrawn?

Comment: @learnmore: If $g$ is analytic, then either $g=0$ or the zeros are isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^2 = 0$ then clearly $f=0$ is analytic.

Now assume that $f$ is not identically zero, hence neither are $f^2, f^3$.

We have $|f(z)|^2 = |f(z)^2| $ and similarly for $f^3$.
Then we have (i) $f$ is bounded on any ball and (ii) $f(z) = 0 $ **iff**
$f^2(z) = 0$ **iff** $f^3(z) = 0$.

If $f(z) \neq 0$, we have $f(z) = { f^3(z) \over f^2(z)}$ hence $f$ is analytic for all $z$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$.

Now suppose $f(z_0) = 0$. Since $f^2,f^3$ are analytic, there are integers $m_2,m_3$ and analytic functions $g_2,g_3$ such that $g_2(z_0) \neq 0$,
$g_3(z_0) \neq 0$ and we can write $f_2(z) = (z-z_0)^{m_2} g_2(z)$,
$f_3(z) = (z-z_0)^{m_3} g_3(z)$.

Since $f^3 = f \cdot f^2$, we have, for nearby $z \neq z_0$, that
$(z-z_0)^{m_3} g_3(z) = f(z) (z-z_0)^{m_2} g_2(z)$ and hence
$f(z) = (z-z_0)^{m_3-m_2} {g_3(z) \over g_2(z) }$. Since $f$ is bounded near
$z_0$ we see that $m_3 \ge m_2$, and since $f(z_0) = 0$, we see that
$m_3 > m_2$, hence $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

Note that there is no a priori requirement that $f$ be continuous.

Comment: Actually, in your proof, the statement "Since $f$ is bounded near $z_0$" uses the continuity of $f$.  I think you can note that $f^2$ is analytic $\implies$ $|f|^2$ is continuous $\implies$  $|f|=\sqrt{|f|^2}$ is continuous.

Comment: I would write it as $f^2$ is analytic near $z_0$ hence $|f|$ is bounded near $z_0$.